# What is the significance of the billboard?

Tags: analysis, the-great-gatsby

In [The Great Gatsby (2013)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1343092/) they make reference to the billboard with the eyes and eye glasses. "Always watching". Several times during the movie they pan and/or zoom to the billboard as if it were judging. What is the significance of this billboard and the eyes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a standard academic question posed to students reading the novel. I remember it being on a test in high school. I'm willing to bet it's discussed in the cliff notes to the novel. To a degree the answer is in the eye opinion holder...What I mean is that you'll probably find other opinions out there, like: the eyes symbolize that God is dead, or the glasses symbolize corruption, but the best answer is that the eyes are symbolic of God watching man. This is the answer you should put on the test.

You can read some commentary on the symbol [here](http://www.ovtg.de/3_arbeit/englisch/gatsby/Symbols.html), and [here](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Where_does_a_symbol_of_God_appear_in_The_Great_Gatsby), and [here](http://www.shmoop.com/great-gatsby/eyes-dr-t-j-eckleburg-valley-ashes-below-them-symbol.html), and [here](http://lastroseofsummer2.hubpages.com/hub/Doctor-TJ-Eckleburg-and-The-Great-Gatsby-Eyes).

Comment: "the eyes are symbolic of God watching man" is what I was assuming. Seems I wasn't so far off.

Comment: you were right on the money!